# creating bold text in pdf from ipad

Tags: ipad, pdf

I have an `iPad` app that creates a `pdf` and works fine however I am trying to get the headings bold.

Currently I have:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontwithname:@"arial" size 12];
```

I would like to know what I need to add to make the text **bold** as well.

Many thanks

Comment: Use a different font name perhaps? Or something like `boldSystemFontOfSize:`

Comment: I have been looking at this but I am not sure of the syntax.

Comment: Richard can I suggest that you accept @H2CO3's answer instead seeing as he arrived at this solution first only to be copied by another user. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:12.0];
```